# In Javascript, is there a way to know the path is changed?

Tags: javascript, browser, single-page-application

I am wondering, if there is a way to know(using events) that the path is changed? I looked into both onpopstate & onhashchange. Both are not what I am looking for. My current requirements are, in a single page application:

1. When the url is changed from one to something else, I want a function to be called.
2. When the page is loaded initially, the function for the current page to be called.

Are these possible with native API's in the browser?

Comment: The event is not triggered when the path is changed.

Comment: I just checked in an isolated environment. `onpopstate` handler is not called when `history.pushState('', 'New Page Title', '/signup');` kind of calls are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event, which fires when the page has finished loading:

```js
function code(){
    console.log('page loaded')
}

window.addEventListener('load', code)
```

To listen for `pushState` changes, you can override the default `pushState` behavior:

```js
function trigger() {
  console.log('state change')
}

var pushState = history.pushState;
history.pushState = function(state) {
  if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
    history.onpushstate({state: state});
  }
  trigger()
  return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
};

history.pushState(null, null, '/endpoint')
```

Comment: This can probably be used for the requirement #2. But, is there any API available to call a function when the path gets changed using `pushState` or by clicking on `a` tag?

Comment: @user175405 I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is a workaround. So, there are no straightforward API's available, yet?

Comment: @user175405 No, there does not appear to be one. There is [`webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onHistoryStateUpdated), but that is only available for browser extensions.

Comment: I wonder then, how react-router-dom and many other client side routing libraries executed functions on url change!

Comment: @user175405 They may also be overriding `pushState`'s default behavior, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @user175405 I can't speak to React, but I assume it's pretty similar to Angular. Angular is already handling all the routing, and rendering any anchor elements in the dom, so it's trivial for it to execute a callback whenever the url changes. Note that manually changing the url in the browser bar will re-rendering the entire app, and not just load the new route from inside the existing SPA.